# XSLT - extract the value of an attribute of a node that has of sub-element that has a target attribute value and element value?

Tags: xml, xslt

First of all, my apologies for the convoluted Title, but I hope that the example information I am posting will make my question clearer!

I have an XML document that looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Setting Name="LDAPS" Type="htf:map">

<Setting Name="LDAP-A" Type="htf:map">
  <Setting Name="MY_URL" Type="xsd:string">ldap://xxxx:yyy</Setting>
  <Setting Name="Name" Type="xsd:string">MY_LDAP1</Setting>
  <Setting Name="somethingelse" Type="xsd:string">SOMEOTHERVALUE1</Setting>
</Setting>


<Setting Name="LDAP-B" Type="htf:map">
  <Setting Name="MY_URL" Type="xsd:string">ldap:abc:xyz</Setting>
  <Setting Name="Name" Type="xsd:string">MY_TARGET_LDAP</Setting>
  <Setting Name="somethingelse" Type="xsd:string">SOMEOTHERVALUE2</Setting>
  <Setting Name="somethingnew" Type="xsd:string">SOMENEWVALUE</Setting>
</Setting>


<Setting Name="LDAP-C" Type="htf:map">
  <Setting Name="MY_URL" Type="xsd:string">ldap:abc:xxxx</Setting>
  <Setting Name="Name" Type="xsd:string">MY_LDAP3</Setting>
  <Setting Name="somethingelse" Type="xsd:string">SOMEOTHERVALUE3</Setting>
  <Setting Name="somethingelseotherdata" Type="xsd:string">SOMEOTHERDATAVALUE3</Setting>
</Setting>

</Setting>

</Configuration>
```

Given the XML above, I am FIRST trying to find the IF there is a node that has the Xpath /Configuration/Setting/Setting that has a sub-node that has an attribute named "Name" and where the value of the sub-node matches a value I am looking for (e.g. In the example data above, the first thing I am trying to find is the sub-node in the XML whose "Name" attribute is "Name", and where the value of the node is "MY_TARGET_LDAP").

Then, IF there is such a sub-node, what I trying to find (and this is the end goal) is the value of "Name" attribute of /Configuration/Setting/Setting node.

So, for the example XML above, what the final result should be:

```
LDAP-B
```

I am trying to do most of the work using XSLT, and so far, what I have is the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Configuration/Setting">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Configuration/Setting/Setting">
  <ldapname> <xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/> </ldapname>
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <response>
          <respname> <xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/> </respname>
              <respvalue><xsl:value-of select="."/> </respvalue>
          </response> <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am using xsltproc on a Redhat machine to test and when I run that against the sample XML I am getting:

```
xsltproc generic1.xsl generic-test.xml:

<html xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">    <body>

<ldapname>LDAP-A</ldapname><response><respname>MY_URL</respname><respvalue>ldap://xxxx:yyy</respvalue></response>
<response><respname>Name</respname><respvalue>MY_LDAP1</respvalue></response>
<response><respname>somethingelse</respname><respvalue>SOMEOTHERVALUE1</respvalue></response>

<ldapname>LDAP-B</ldapname><response><respname>MY_URL</respname><respvalue>ldap:abc:xyz</respvalue></response>
<response><respname>Name</respname><respvalue>MY_TARGET_LDAP</respvalue></response>
<response><respname>somethingelse</respname><respvalue>SOMEOTHERVALUE2</respvalue></response>
<response><respname>somethingnew</respname><respvalue>SOMENEWVALUE</respvalue></response>

<ldapname>LDAP-C</ldapname><response><respname>MY_URL</respname><respvalue>ldap:abc:xxxx</respvalue></response>
<response><respname>Name</respname><respvalue>MY_LDAP3</respvalue></response>
<response><respname>somethingelse</respname><respvalue>SOMEOTHERVALUE3</respvalue></response>
<response><respname>somethingelseotherdata</respname><respvalue>SOMEOTHERDATAVALUE3</respvalue>              </response>

</body></html>
```

(NOTE: Please don't pay attention to the BODY and HTML tags in the above... I am not actually using HTML but it just makes it easier for me to look at when I test.)

In any event, can someone suggest how I can modify the XSLT to accomplish what I described above?

Thanks!
Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow this correctly, all you need to do is:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="Configuration/Setting/Setting[Setting[@Name='Name']='MY_TARGET_LDAP']/@Name"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes there is at most one `Setting` that satisfies the criteria in predicates. If there are more, only the value of the `Name` attribute of the first one of these will be returned.